# Inheriting ViewController class into another ViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I wanted to use a library however it required me to change MyTabBarViewController class to its own class ([*its own TabBarController*](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar/blob/master/RAMAnimatedTabBarController/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.swift) *- 138*) installed using cocoapod. I couldn't figure out how to do it (or if it's possible) but that would be nice for me to be able to use MyTabBarViewController as well so I can have my stuff separated, such as `viewDidLoad` and my functions.

I was using MyTabBarViewController instead of this but the library requires me to change it to this. 
[image]

Is there a way to make my TabBarVC getting called with a line inside the library's TabBarVC? Or should I write inside the library's TabViewController?

Comment: Not sure of the question but to answer this: "Is there a way to make my TabBarVC getting called with a line inside the library's TabBarVC?" You can use a swizzle for that if you don't have the source. Check out NHHipster, there is an example of swizzling a method of a view controller on that site. "Or should I write inside the library's TabViewController?" What do you mean? A library is a binary file, unless you have the source. If you have the source editing that directly is easier than a swizzle.

Comment: Inherit your tab bar controller from RAMAnimatedTabBarController?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I actually tried to ask if this is possible and how to do it.. Can you please give me an example how to inherit from my TabBarController?